# Haskell - mapping the odd placed values and the even placed values differently

Tags: haskell, mapping

is there an easy way. To take a list of numbers, say 123456. Then multiply the odd placed by three and the even placed by 1.

i.e. (1 * 3) + (2 * 1) + (3 * 3) + (4*1) + (5*3) + (6*1)

i was thinking the map function somewhere along the lines. But i don't know how to map *3 to just the odd placed values. Oh and if you could give me the version not in prelude that would be great like the actual function or functions, as if its being imported from an external haskell file

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "give me the version not in Prelude."  The function you're asking for isn't in Prelude.  If you want the implementation of `map` itself, then this sounds like homework—if it is, please add the "homework" tag.

Comment: no i understand what map does. i just don't know how to map the multiply by three to only the odd placed numbers.
i.e. 98732
that means i only want to multiply the digits 9, 7, 2 by 3. How do i do that? btw i'm new, whats this homework thing?

Comment: Between this and your other post it is clear that you are implementing ISBN numbers in Haskell. The question is - is this homework or an exam for a course? If it is, then these questions should be tagged *homework*.

Answer (score 14):

Okay, as I wrote in a comment earlier, `zipWith (*) (cycle [3,1]) xs` is what you're looking for. But first, a minor nitpick: the head of the list I would call the zeroth element, that's why I have switched the 1 and 3 around :-)

Let's go through a simple example; let `xs` be `[9,8,7,3,2]`. `cycle [3,1]` just repeats its argument over and over so that will be an infinite list starting with [3,1,3,1,3,1,..]. What `zipWith f xs ys` does is take the head element of `xs` and the head element of `ys` and apply `f` (which should be a function of two arguments) to those elements - the result of `f` then goes onto the front of the result of `zipWith`. If one of xs or ys becomes empty, we're done; otherwise we just keep going.

So the first element of the result will be `(3 * 9)`, then `(1 * 8)`, `(3 * 7)`, `(1 * 3)`, `(3 * 2)` and we're done!

You can have a look at the definition of `zipWith` [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.1/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#zipWith).

If you *really* don't want to use the predefined functions, you could define an 'alternating map' taking two functions instead of one, applying the first of these to the head of your argument list and switching the functions around on the recursive call. I'll let you figure out the details there...

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The `xs` does seem to come out of nowhere! I should just have named the function.

Answer (score 2):

What about this, assuming `xs` is your list of numbers:

```
map (uncurry ($)) (zip (cycle [((*) 1), ((*) 3)]) xs)
```

Here's how this works:

`[((*) 1), ((*) 3)]` is a list containing two functions. The first multiplies a number by one; the second multiplies a number by three.

`cycle [...]` creates an infinite list of those two functions, repeating one after the other, [×1, ×3, ×1, ×3 ...]

`zip (cycle [...]) xs` takes your numbers and pairs them with the functions. So if `xs` is [1..6] then you get [(×1, 1), (×3, 2), (×1, 3), (×3, 4), (×1, 5), (×3, 6)].

The `$ :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` function is a combinator; it takes a function a→b and applies it to a value. So `map (uncurry ($)) (zip ...)` takes the list of (function, number) pairs and applies the function to the number. You need `uncurry` because the list contains pairs, so the signature of the function to map needs to be `((a -> b), a) -> b`.

This leaves you with the resulting list; in this case [1, 6, 3, 12, 5, 18].

Comment: This is the most direct implementation of the task, but it seems a bit hard to read. Maybe it's just my lack of experience with this style, but it feels like the reading order is all wonky (the actual behavior is spread out between arguments and arguments to arguments) and the punctuation outweighs the semantic characters. `($) ( ( [(() ), (() )]) )` — holy cow!

Comment: @Chuck You could introduce "explaining bindings" with `let` and `where` if you like.

Comment: yeah okay i'm only a beginner with haskell, that looks mega confusing can;'t we put some $'s in there somewhere to clear it up. Too many brackets

Comment: Maybe `sum (zipWith (*) (cycle [1,3]) xs)` is a bit clearer in this case?

Comment: @yatima2975 minus the `sum`—I think @Abstract wants the result as a list—`zipWith` is *much* neater. You should submit this as an answer.

Comment: `((*) 3)` can be much more easily written as `(*3)`. These are called operator sections and are worth learning.

Comment: thanks all for the help :). Yatima thats awesome, i actually fully understand that.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to use an accumulating map, using the accumulating parameter to flag whether it's on an 'even' or 'odd' cycle.  I see nobody else has done that so let's see how it goes...

```
import Data.List (mapAccumL)

yourFunc = snd . mapAccumL mult True -- 'True' represents an odd index, starting from 1
  where
    mult True  x = (False, 3 * x)
    mult False x = (True , x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use map, just use zip first:

```
let list' = zip [1..] list
in map (\(cnt,val) -> if odd cnt then val * 3 else val) list'
```

Above you can see how to make a result dependent on the index as well as the value at that index.  This is a fairly general solution that, by replacing the lambda (first argument of `map`), you can make many variants.  The more specialized solution using `cycle` and `zipWith` is much shorter and perfectly readable to those comfortable in Haskell.

edited and fleshed out after the statement this is **not** homework.

Comment: can you explain that a little further?

Comment: I intentionally left it as a (very large) hint until you answered the "is this homework" question.  This is basically done, I don't see what further really needs explained.

Comment: mmk i'll search elsewhere then, i understand but that only gets me a list of tuples, with the place value on the left, value of the integer on the right. Thats fantastic but what you do there i can only seem to grab one of those two variables. Nor can i put a filter to just grab the odd or even ones. Whats this homework thing (for the second time)

Comment: Yes, it is Haskell.  And Abstract, if you don't know what Homework is then you can read its [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homework) and answer yes or no.

Comment: oh i didn't realise you guys actually meant homework from school. Nah its called we do C at Uni and i wanted to learn haskell on the side, so i'm attempting my task 1 in haskell. Its not part of the course or anything just an interest

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this point-free style, there's no better way than using `cycle` and some form of `zip`.  (Point-free means, roughly, "without naming let-bound or lambda-bound variables.")  I have two questions:

- How many different ways will you need to generalize this computation?
- How familiar are your readers with `cycle` and other lesser-known list functions (there must be a hundred list functions)?

The more general your problem and the more familiar your readers, the more likely I am to recommend point-free style.  For a one-off solution aimed at readers not very familiar with Haskell, I might try a recursive function:

```
mult31 [] = 0
mult31 [x:x':xs] = x * 3 + x' * 1 + mult31 xs
mult31 [x] = x * 3
```

Or if you want to get clever, you can use a pair of alternating functions:

```
mult31 = m3
  where m3 (x:xs) = x * 3 + m1 xs
        m3 []     = 0
        m1 (x:xs) = x * 1 + m3 xs
        m1 []     = 0
```

Either of these functions will seem less natural to a Haskell veteran than something that uses a zip function with `cycle`, but for someone just starting out, they may be easier to follow.

Comment: nah Zipwith and cycle work really well but thanks for the help : )